# How to compare time with preset time in java

Tags: java, time, compare

I'm trying to make a program that plays a sound according to the time of day/night, I need to know how to compare the current time with a preset int or something along the lines of that. Thanks for feedback!

Comment: You know that this is not a great question right? It's seems like you don't know what you really want...

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please read [ask].  Your question  is too vague and unclear.  Please provide **specific** details.  We are not mind readers.

Comment: Joda data time there is a compare to you can use that.

Comment: Do some research into java.util.Timer

Comment: Search on [executors](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/executors.html), timer, Joda-Time, and java.time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
Date d = new Date();
```

from the java.util library which will get the time from the current date and you can use that to compare it with a time given the time is in the right format.

Comment: Wouldn't `new Date()` be easier to use than that?

Comment: That method returns a long. If he wants to compare it with another time, that time cannot fit in an int.

Answer (score 0):

you can get current time with `System.currentTimeMillis();`

and you can convert any time to time millis format. if you have `Date`, you can call `getTime()` method to get time millis. if you have `Calendar`, you can use `getTime()` to get Date, and then calling again `getTime()` method over returned value to get time millis.

```
Date d = new Date();
.
.
.

if (d.getTime() > System.currentTimeMillis()){
.
.
}
```

if you want to make process over seconds, you can divide millis to 1000, and if you want to make process over minutes, you can dived millis to 1000*60 and for other times, you can use simply multipliers.

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
.
.
.
// for instance this is a simple equality for days equations.
if ( c.getTime().getTime()/(1000*60*60*24) == System.currentTimeMillis()/(1000*60*60*24) ){
.
.
}
```